# PHP mutidimensional array traverse values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array that I want to traverse using `foreach` (with keys and values).

My problem is that the arrays are not always the same (i.e., the arrays are dynamic since I receive them in a response). How can I traverse them in a loop? Here is an example of the structure of the arrays:

First array:

```
Array(
[id] => 
[client_customer_id] => 
[reference] => 
[client_order_id] => 
[status] => 
[name_search_records] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [first_name] => 
                [last_name] => 
                [middle_name] => 
                [suffix] => 
                [name_type] => 
                [services] => 
                    (
                        [ucc] => Array
                            (
                                [name_search_record_id] => 
                                [request_header_id] => 
                                [is_at_any_address] => 
                                [status] => 
                                [create_date] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Second array:

```
Array(
[id] => 
[client_customer_id] => 
[reference] => 
[client_order_id] => 
[status] => Canceled
[property_search_records] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [order_detail_id] => 
                [address_line1] => address
                [county_id] => 
                [district_id] =>
                [state_id] => 
                [services] => Array
                    (
                        [flood_lol] => Array
                            (
                                [property_search_record_id] => 
                                [request_header_id] => 
                                [is_lol] => 
                                [lender] => 
                                [lender_address_line1] => 
                                [lender_address_line2] => 
                                [lender_city] => 
                                [lender_zip] => 
                                [status] => 
                                [create_date] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get your question. Are you interesting in determining which key holds an array and which doesn't? In that case, you can do something like this:

```
function check_arr($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            echo $key . ' is array' . '<br>';
            check_arr($value);
        } else {
            echo $key . ' is not array' . '<br>';
        }
    }
}


$arr1 = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => array(
        'd' => 3,
        'e' => array(
            'f' => 4,
            'g' => array(
                'h' => 5,
                'i' => 6,
                'j' => array(
                    'k' => 7,
                    'l' => array(
                        'm' => 8
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);


$arr2 = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => array(
        'c' => 2,
        'd' => 3
    ),
    'e' => 4
);
```

Output for `check_arr($arr1)`:

```
a is not array
b is not array
c is array
d is not array
e is array
f is not array
g is array
h is not array
i is not array
j is array
k is not array
l is array
m is not array
```

Output for `check_arr($arr2)`:

```
a is not array
b is array
c is not array
d is not array
e is not array
```

You can go as deep as you want with your arrays and you can add your own logic when you encounter a key that holds an array of interest. Is this what you are looking for?